# Finding the interval for increase of the function $y =x^2e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Problem :

Find the interval in which the function $y =x^2e^{-x}$ is increasing .

My approach :

We can take first derivative to the find the increase or decrease of function ie.

$y'=2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}$

finding the critical point by putting y'=0

$ \Rightarrow xe^{-x}(2-x)=0$

$\Rightarrow x =0, x =2$ are the critical point ( please clarify here)

Now if we take second derivative at these critical points :

$y'' = x^2e^{-x}-4xe^{-x}+2e^{-x}$ ;

If we put x =0 then we get  2 ( which is positive ) that means at 0 function attains minimum values....

please help me to find the interval in which it increases...As the function attains minimum value at 0, I think from 0 onwards it start increasing.. but unable to locate the interval ....

Comment: You did too much calculation, the second derivative is irrelevant. We need to take the first derivative and look closely at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $e^{-x}$ is always positive, so you only need to look at $x(2-x)$.  Figure out on what interval it is positive.  It is positive if the two factors are both positive or both negative.  But the first factor is negative only if $x<0$, and on that interval $2-x$ is positive.  Next, notice that $2-x$ is positive precisely if $x<2$.  You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Then the answer is (0,2) , this is the only interval in which x(2-x) is having same sign.... Please suggest..

Comment: Correct. ${{{{}}}}$